# React-Native : Can't show remote images in release mode on android device

Tags: android, image, react-native

im runing a simple react-native application in my android device (samsung 9, Android 9, API 28), so on debug mode it's work fine using this commande line :

```
react-native run-android
```

this is the result :

[image: 1]

but in relase mode (`react-native run-android --variant=release`) , image not showing :

[image: 2]

my simple code :

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={ {uri:'http://i.imgur.com/GRIZj68.png'} } style={{width:200,height:200} } />
      <Text>HOLA</Text>  
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

any help please !

Comment: been my problem too, i thought it may be frameworks bug. i still dont know the reason.

Comment: this issue reproduced just in android 9 i guess

Comment: @Amas you  need to add https

Answer (score 11):

Android pie (9) doesn't allow non https images to be rendered, so you have to change your http requests to https or to set a `networkSecurityConfig` in your `Manifest` application tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then in your xml folder you now have to create a file named network_security_config just like the way you have named it in the Manifest and from there the content of your file should be like this to enable all requests without encryptions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

source:  `https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config`

Comment: Wow I tried all kind of debugs and I just couldn't find why my app wont show images on release mode, thank you very much, even tho I didn't modify my androidManifest I just told the backend developers to use https instead http, but you guided me to the right direction

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure it out and this comment was the right one , I have't xml folder I added it under ( android/app/main/res ) and then the file network_security_config.xml after that it works

Answer (score 0):

We were having crashes and issues in development with our icons not being written out and appearing like **images_homeactive**. This caused **react-native-navigation** to crash our app

This occurred when we upgraded to compileSDKVersion = 28.

[Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

[this prevents your application from connecting to the React Native packager. The changes below allow cleartext traffic in debug builds.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#network-security-config-api-level-28)

```
../app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="${isDebug}" tools:targetApi="28">

../android/app/build.gradle
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [isDebug:false]
    }
    debug {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [isDebug:true]
    }
}
```

So thankful to stumble upon Ahmed's answer. 
Hope this helps someone.