# <Image> url not showing for android React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `<Image>` and `<ImageBackground>` with `source:{{ uri: url }}` inside my React Native project.

But the problem is an image is not showing inside `Android` simulator (But `IOS` simulator is fine)

This is my component

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image,
} from 'react-native'

import { Header } from 'react-navigation'
import { dimens } from '../../../services/variables'

const CustomHeader = ({ bgSrc }) => (
  <ImageBackground
    source={
        bgSrc
          ? { uri: bgSrc }
          : require('../../../assets/images/placeholder_image_bg_wide.png')
      }
    style={styles.header}
  >
    <Text style={styles.description}>First element</Text>
    <Image source={{ uri: 'https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg' }} style={{ width: 200, height: 45, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
    <Text style={styles.description}>Second element</Text>
    <Image source={{ uri: 'http://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300.jpg' }} style={{ width: 200, height: 45 }} />
    <Text style={styles.title}>Last element 1</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
)

export default CustomHeader

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    minHeight: Header.HEIGHT,
    height: dimens.header.height,
    marginTop: dimens.header.marginTop,
    paddingLeft: dimens.header.paddingLeft,
    paddingBottom: dimens.header.paddingBottom,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
  },
  title: {
    ...dimens.header.title,
  },
  description: {
    ...dimens.header.description,
  },
})
```

I also already added permissions inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is the image of my both simulators
[image]

You will see that on `IOS` simulator `<Image>` is showing correctly but not on `Android` none images were show (Both `http` and `https`)

So how can i fix these and make Android simulator works, Thanks!

Comment: it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012702/react-native-cant-show-remote-images-in-release-mode-on-android-device?noredirect=1#comment98671245_56012702

Comment: According to screenshot, i think internet is not working in your android emulator...

Comment: Probably @AnkitMakwana has right. You can also try to rebuild android project and try to run it again. Also rerun android emulator.

Comment: @AnkitMakwana right the internet is not working in my android simulator, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have said this before in another question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263771/8826164
but there is an issue with Image component is that if first time initialize the component with `source={{uri : 'some link'}}` it may not work (at least not for me when I fetch image from HTTPS URL from Firebase storage). The trick is you have to trigger a change to source props like first you need to keep
source to `source={undefined}` and then change to `source={{uri : 'some link'}}`. And it seems like you have hard-coded URL for `uri`, so you might fall into the same issue as I did

Answer (score -2):

Before :
<Image source={{ url: `http://stitch2stitch.azurewebsites.net/assets/img/FileFormats/${result}.png`}} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, }} />

After :
<Image source={{uri: `http://stitch2stitch.azurewebsites.net/assets/img/FileFormats/${result}.png`}} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, }} />

just change from url to uri works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).